# "Module is not missing constant Model" - Rails 3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I have namespaced my models and controllers within my app.

when I try to visit admin/stories.html (NameSpace::Admin::StoriesController)

I keep getting an error "NameSpace is not missing constant Story!"

here's a copy of my controller for reference:

```
class NameSpace::Admin::StoriesController < NameSpace::ApplicationController

  layout "admin"
  before_filter :admin_login_required

  cache_sweeper NameSpace::StorySweeper, :only => [:update,:destroy]

  # expose is provided by the DecentExposure Gem
  expose(:stories) { current_place.stories.where(:state => %w{ submitted published }).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(25) }
  expose(:story)

  def create
    if params[:success] == "1"
      Story.find_or_create_by_media_id(params[:media_id])      
      redirect_to admin_stories_url, :notice => "Successfully created story! It should appear here in a few minuntes once it's been processed."
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "There was an error when creating your story!<br>If this happens again, please contact support@#{APP_CONFIG[:domain]}".html_safe
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if story.update_attributes(params[:story])
      redirect_to admin_stories_url, :notice => "Successfully updated story."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    story.remove!
    redirect_to admin_stories_url, :notice => "Story successfully destroyed!"
  end

end
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.0.beta1 with REE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Rails error

Fixed by updating to the latest version of Rails 3.1.0.beta1 on Rails/Master @ github.

```
# Gemfile
gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Bah, some information on the specific error or reason for it would be useful for future reference (getting this is Rails 2.3.11)

Comment: Agreed -- could you add some more info on how you tracked this down? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys - Im sure it was a comment on one of the github issues - maybe from JoshPeek, advising to upgrade to bleeding edge. That solution worked for me so I didn't dig any deeper. Good luck

Comment: Love a solution for those stuck on older versions (3.0.11 for me)

Answer (score 1):

Using `module` instead of the colon notation for the class name to indicate namespacing fixed the issue for me in Rails 3.0.15

e.g.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  ...
  end
end
```

vs

```
class Foo::Bar
end
```